# Python socket sendall failed without sleep

Tags: python, sockets, lua

New to python, I have implemented the following the following python code to send just some dummy load to a TCP client.

```
# echo-server.py
import socketserver
import time
import socket

HOST = "192.168.219.1"  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 30000  # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print(f"Connected by {addr}")
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print(data.decode())
        conn.sendall(b"-0.25")
        time.sleep(2)
```

The above code works fine. However, if I delete the last line `time.sleep(2)`, then the client received nothing.

The client code is on a robot arm written in lua:

```
function string.fromBytes(t)
   local bytearr = {}
   for _, v in ipairs(t) do
      local utf8byte = v < 0 and (0xff + v + 1) or v
      table.insert(bytearr, string.char(utf8byte))
   end
   return table.concat(bytearr)
end

port = 30000
ip = "192.168.219.1"

tcp.client.connect(ip,port)
sleep(1)
print("UESR connect server")
tcp.client.send_str_data(ip, port, "Hello PC")
recv={}
while(#recv < 1)
do
    sleep(0.2)
    recv=tcp.client.recv_asc_data(ip, port)
end
r_str = string.fromBytes(recv)
r_val = tonumber(r_str)
set_global_variable("V_D_z", r_val)
print(r_val)
tcp.client.disconnect(ip,port)
```

Could anyone kindly point to me what is the problem?

Comment: Can you show the other program too?

Comment: @AKX The client code is added, but it is written in lua.

Comment: Hmm - I'd be tempted to say this might be a bug in that Lua client library when the server terminates the connection too quickly.

Comment: @AKX You mean the tcp.client part of the lua code?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like the library code there drops the message to read if the TCP connection is closed too quickly.

Comment: No. The bug is in the OP's code. Where did the server close the socket? *Did* it close the socket? or just let it leak? And why the sleep in the client code? It doesn't accomplish anything: the `recv()` will block. And if it returns zero the client should exit the loop, not keep trying to read from a socket whose peer has disconnected.

Comment: @user207421 It's in a `with` statement, [and for `socket` objects exiting the with statement context means closing the socket](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/socket.py#L240-L242).

Comment: Also, @user207421, I tried out OP's server with a simple equivalent Python client, and it works fine without a sleep.

Comment: @AKX Several more issues to go. The bug you suggest is not credible. There is no way LUA could even know that the TCP connection was closed 'too quickly'. This doesn't have any actual meaning in TCP. The FIN arrives after all the data.

Comment: @user207421 OP says "The client code is on a robot arm" – are you really saying it's not credible that there's an embedded TCP stack/library that can misbehave? :)

Comment: Yes, I am saying exactly that, but about the client library you mentioned first, not the TCP stack you are now switching to. If receiving the last segment didn't work, nothing would. But he should certainly remove all the sleeps.

Comment: @user207421 Please also note that the Lua code has no "socket" object but connections are referred to using `ip` and `port` alone; I think it's _entirely_ credible that there's a bug in the `tcp.client` stuff that drops all buffers for a given `(ip, port)` pair the moment it realizes a connection has been closed, no matter if there is still unread data there.

Comment: @user207421 Fine, amended my earlier comment to "embedded TCP stack/library". But that's semantics and beside the point for OP's case.